# Dynamically Set Out Of Browser Height and Width

Tags: silverlight

I have a Silverlight 5 Application that we run Out Of Browser. I would like to know if there is some way to set the Out Of Browser Window Height and Width dynamically in code.

Everyone has a different size monitor. I don’t want the people with the larger monitors to be limited to the screen of the smallest size monitor.

I would either base it on the Users Id or if possible detecting the monitor dimensions.

Comment: did the answer help

Answer (score 0):

This may help,

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e) { MyForm = new MyForm();

this.RootVisual = startupWindow;

this.MainWindow.Width = startupWindow.Width; this.MainWindow.Height = startupWindow.Height; }
```